# Question on spatial sampling for non-linear and/or non-uniform arrays

Tags: frequency, frequency-spectrum, beamforming, spatial

I am a little confused as to how to compute the nyquist criterion for a sensor array that is not linear, and/or non-uniform. For the linear, uniformly spaced case, the spatial nyquist is delimited by finding the half-wavelength that fits between the space of two adjacent sensors. Thus, if the distance between two sensors is given by $d$, then the highest frequency that is allowed is given by:

$$d < \frac{\lambda}{2} = \frac{c}{2f}$$

Where $c$ is the speed of light, and $f$ is the frequency of the signal. And so therefore, the highest frequency allowed such that no spatial aliasing occurs is given by:

$$
f < \frac{c}{2d}
$$

So my question is twofold:

I) What is the spatial nyquist for arrays that are uniformly spaced, but non-linear, (for example, 10 sensors evenly spaced on a circle)?

II) What is the spatial nyquist for cases where the array is non-uniform and non-linear. (for example, some odd shaped number of sensors placed arbitrarily).

I *think* it has to do with the largest distance between them, but I am not clear on this, because, well, what distances do you care about?

Thanks

Comment: It seems that these rules would be analogous to time-domain sampling at an irregular rate. I'm not aware of any specific criterion that applies in that case, but that doesn't mean that it doesn't exist.

Comment: Wouldn't the spatial Nyquist depend on the shortest distance between antennas?

Comment: @JimClay I dont think so - I think it depends on the longest distance between two consecutive antennas. Its like a group of 10 who want to run a marathon together - they can only move as fast as the slowest person. Similarly, I believe if we have a non-uniform array, the largest distance dictates the maximum frequency that can be represented by the group of antennas. (Thats my current understanding at least. What I do not get is how is this largest measure computed, between which antennas, etc.)

Comment: @JasonR Yes, I am sure it exists. Cant seem to find anything on this for either temporal or spatial case via google though.

Comment: @Mohammad: It's possible that there could be some results in the field of compressed sensing that might apply here. I don't know much about it, but I've heard the nonuniform time-domain sampling problem formulated in that kind of framework before. You typically have to make some assumptions about the signal's sparsity in order for it to work, though.

Comment: The advantage of irregular sampling (or element spacing in this case) is that you don't have aliasing anymore (so technically, I don't  think there is a Nyquist rule anymore). For sensor arrays this means you don't get grating lobes. However, there is no free lunch. The price you pay is elevated, irregular sidelobes. But as others have noted, it's hard to say how to quantify information loss from the irregular sampling. It probably depends on what type of signal you're sampling, but I'm not sure.